# JSP refresh page through servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, page-refresh

I'd like to using servlet code to refresh jsp page.

The "my_list.jsp" is a page with a list of items
The "my_add.jsp" is a page that user can input something to add items to the list in "my_list.jsp"

The following figure is the current design.

[image]

User click "add items" in "my_list.jsp" and there will be a pop-up "my_add.jsp".
After user finishes inputing and click "Add button" to add the item to the list, it will trigger "AddServlet.java" to add the item.

```
AddServlet.java

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

    AddItem();
    resp.sendRedirect("/my_add.jsp");
    resp.setHeader("REFRESH", "0");
}
```

Because the user may add more items, so I don't want "my_add.jsp" page close after adding an item.
So I write the following in "AddServlet.java"

```
resp.sendRedirect("/my_add.jsp");
resp.setHeader("REFRESH", "0");
```

But now, after user clicks "Add button" in "my_add.jsp" page, "my_list.jsp" will not update. "my_list.jsp" will update only if I click "Close button" in "my_add.jsp" or press "Refresh" in "my_list.jsp".

I would like to know if there's any way to refresh "my_list.jsp" page after clicking "Add button" in "my_add.jsp" ?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: You should say what is the technical organisation of the 2 pages : one single html page => ok all can be done in java + jsp or 2 html pages => you will need javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two pages such as `"my_list.jsp" and "my_add.jsp"` . use a `jquery` dialog from **my_list.jsp** . So it will trigger the dialog as you have shown in the my_add.jsp.

Now just make an ajax call from the `my_list.jsp` after the jquery confirmation.So that you can print the success value in the **my_list.jsp** without refreshing it .

Hope this helps !!